# Should I avoid adding arbitrary fields to HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, dom

I tested adding arbitrary fields to HTML elements in JavaScript and it worked as expected:

```
const element = document.getElementById('element-id');
element.greet = (message) => { alert(message); };
element.friendElement = document.createElement('div');
element.greet(element.friendElement.innerText);
```

The alert shows up with the message, but I'm concerned:

1. Do all the major browsers support this behavior?
2. Is there a pattern for choosing new field name to make sure it won't conflict with names that the browsers use as fields for the elements?
3. Is there any reason I should avoid adding arbitrary fields to HTML elements?

I wish HTML elements had another standard field like oncustomevent that can be set to a user defined function.

Comment: It's possible everywhere, but a bad idea. Use standalone functions or classes or Maps instead to avoid confusing readers of the code. Similarly, people don't put arbitrary properties on arrays. `const arr = []; arr.foobar = 10;` isn't done

Comment: The DOM is not a place where you store your data. It's huge, retrieving values from elements is dead slow compared to well-structured JS data. There's no pattern to avoid naming conflicts, and the data in the elements is globally available.

Comment: A true story of storing data to the DOM. A blog was edited by a community. In the editor there were command buttons having `data-cmd` attribute, which of value was the name of a method in `cmd` object. Buttons were filtered by an authorization system, regular users couldn't delete blogs, because Delete button was not in the UI. However, the delete method was in `cmd`, and a user deleted a blog just by changing the value of the `data-cmd` attribute of a button from 'save' to `delete`. Though a lot of things were wrong, that globally stored data made it really easy to misuse the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT

I just learned about [Custom Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) that can be used to add custom handlers to elements.

---

### Previous Answer

Most of the answers to this question have these two parts:

1. **Why storing none DOM data in DOM elements is wrong?**
2. **What is the alternative solution?**

Originally I was looking for the first part only, then reading more about second part, found out it is really important to consider alternative solutions to make the decision. I will also include these two parts in my answer.

### Why storing none DOM data in DOM elements is wrong?

Many people may start learning web development with HTML, then move to CSS and JS. This make them see the HTML as the back bone of the web app, that CSS and JS are plugged here and there to it. When designing the logic of the application around the HTML elements, storing non-visual data at DOM elements makes total sense and it seems very unfair to find out that JS objects and functions cannot be referenced there.

The alternative and correct view is to see the HTML and CSS and JS as three independent pillars of the app that have some ways of communication. Each pillar should encapsulate the data it needs for its internal work. DOM elements are there to tell browsers how to render the page. They shouldn't be used as a referencing point to address data used by JS.

### What is the alternative solution?

The supported solutions are:

1. Using global objects
2. Serializing into DOM elements' dataset

The unsupported solutions are:

1. Adding arbitrary fields to DOM elements (works with functions too!)

Each one of these solutions have their own problems (I won't go to details here), so I ended up using another solution:

**Capturing**

I need to rephrase the problem to explain this.
The problem is that the scope that objects are defined is different than the scope they are needed.

Capturing helps teleport objects from one scope to another scope. To apply this solution, we need to design a hierarchy of scopes in a way that each scope have access to all external objects it needs via its parent scope(s). Here is an example:

Problem:

```
<script>
    window.onload = () => {
        let message = 'Hello, world!';
        // Need to reference message within greet function
        // element's dataset or global object will work 
    };
    function greet() {
        alert(message); // where to find it?
    }
</script>
<button onclick='greet()'>Greet</button>
```

Solution:

```
<script>
    window.onload = () => {
        let message = 'Hello, world!';
        document.getElementById('greeter').onclick = function() {
            alert(message); // capture it
        };
    };
</script>
<button id='greeter'>Greet</button>
```

As you see, I've moved the onclick function into onload function to steal objects from its scope.

Answer (score 2):

It should work, but it's not a good idea, because a future change to the DOM specification might add those properties, and your code would conflict.

The DOM API already provides a place for application-defined string data, the `dataset` property, which corresponds to `data-XXX` attributes. So you can write:

```
element.dataset.message = 'Hello, world';
```

There's nothing equivalent for functions, though. Instead of making it a property, you could just use a regular function.

```
function greet(element) {
    alert(element.dataset.message);
}
```

Comment: In the function example, there is no way to access none-text information of the element. I edited my question to reflect my case that cannot be solved with data-* attributes.

Answer (score 1):

DOM elements are not "namespaces" for related stuff, they are entities with a specific purpose, which is reflected as a particular set of data and behavior. Although there are some objects in JavaScript that serve the purpose of namespacing related functionality (`Math`, `Intl`, etc.), they usually are unique and "famous" enough to be a good exception to the rule.

If you want to associate a particular behavior and/or data with some DOM element, create a separate entity; it can be a full-blown class:

```js
class ElementGreeter {
  constructor(element, friendElement) {
    this.element = element;
    this.friendElement = friendElement;
  }

  greetPrimary() {
    this.greet(this.element.innerText);
  }

  greetFriend() {
    this.greet(this.friendElement.innerText);
  }

  greet(message) {
    alert(message);
  }
}
```

… or a simple function:

```js
const createGreeter = (propName) => (element) => alert(element[propName]);

const greet = createGreeter("innerText");

greet(element);
greet(friendElement);
```